# insert data from csv 

Tags: php, mysql

```
Parts No    Mfg     Cond    LowPrice    AvgPrice    HighPrice  Weighted TotalQty
002805-00   3COM    NEW     25          25          25         N/A      1
0231A085    3COM    NEW     133.75      133.75      133.75     N/A      3
0231A61N    3COM    NEW     253.58      253.58      253.58     N/A      2
0231A61P    3COM    NEW     467.25      467.25      467.25     N/A      1
```

i wana add only partno , mfg and price from this csv format into the table having different field name as define in 1st row but table also contain some other fields.

This is right way to insert??????? Suggestions.

```
    if (($handle = fopen("sample.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
              while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                $i=0;
                if ($scount == 0) {  
                        foreach ($data as $key=>$value){
                         $item[$i++] = $value; 
                         if($value == 'Parts No') $c1 = $key;
                         if($value == 'Mfg') $c2 = $key;if($value == 'Cond') $c3 = $key;

                         if($value == 'AvgPrice') $c4 = $key;

                        }

                }else{
                if($data[$c3] == "NEW" || $data[$c3] == "new"){
                mysql_query("insert into  vable (partno,brand,price)
                    values('".$data[$c1]."','".$data[$c2]."','".$data[$c4]."') ",);}
                }

                $scount++; 

        }
```

Comment: @Bibhas Probably the statement followed by a whopping seven question marks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (partno,brand,price) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s') ";
if (($handle = fopen ( "sample.csv", "r" )) !== FALSE) {
    $x = 0;
    while ( ($data = fgetcsv ( $handle, 10000, "," )) !== FALSE ) {

        if ($x == 0) {
            continue; // Remove headers
        }
        mysql_query ( sprintf ( $sql, mysql_real_escape_string ( $data [0] ), mysql_real_escape_string ( $data [4] ), mysql_real_escape_string ( $data [2] ) ) );
        $x ++;
    }

    fclose ( $handle );
}
```

Comment: Ok ... your example was not clear .. i would ok at it carefully and help you resolve it right away //

Comment: I have posted here an example in Tab Delimited format but origionally my file is in csv format and its working

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to get key value pairs from the csv file where the keys are of first row of csv file

```
function get_data_csv_assoc($file){
    $full_data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        if(($keys = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

        }
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $array = array();
            foreach($keys as $key => $val){
                $array[$val] = $data[$key];
            }
            array_push($full_data,$array);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $full_data;
}
```

Tested..

and after this use key value pairs for data insertion.

```
$return_array = get_data_csv_assoc('filename');
foreach($return_array as $data){
mysql_query("insert into  vable (partno,brand,price)
                    values('".$data["Parts No"]."','".$data['Mfg']."','".$data['LowPrice']."') ",);}
                }
}
```